# Zariski topology on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, zariski-topology

I'm trying to understand the Zariski topology on $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. I've just learned about this new concept and I wanted to compute this topology for a more concrete example to see how it looks but I dont know how to start.

For now I have that $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})= \{(p); \text{p prime} \}\cup \{0\}$ since $\mathbb{Z}$ is principal. Then I don't know how to compute $\text{V}((n))$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ but I don't see how, can someone help me ?

Comment: The first place to start would be writing down the definition for $V((n))$. Can you do that?

Comment: yes it's the set of prime ideals containing (n)

Comment: there's no *n* in the correct spelling of *Zariski*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to  to compute $\text{V}((n))$ you can consider the prime decomposition of $n$ : $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot ... \cdot p_r^{\alpha_r}$, then you have
$$\text{V}((n))=\{(p) ; \text{p prime and }(n)\subset (p)\}=\{(p) ; \text{p prime and }p \mid n \} = \{(p_1),...,(p_n)\}$$

Does that helps you visualizing what the topology looks like ?

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t think about that but now it’s seem really obvious that that was the thing to do…

Comment: I don't think $(0) \in V((n))$ unless $n=0$ in which case $V((0))$ is all of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$.  That matches the fact that $(0)$ is the generic point so the closure of $\{ (0) \}$ should be all of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Downvoted following Daniel Schepler’s absolutely correct remark until the mistake they pointed out is corrected.

Comment: I did correct it ! Thanks for pointing this out!